# Como criar helpers de bloco em Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

Preciso criar um helper para menu dropdown... Mas não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso. Queria um helper em forma de bloco, como é feito com formulários. Ex.:

```
<%= form_for(@teste) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :um_campo %>
<% end %>
```

No meu helper, gostaria de poder fazer algo assim:

```
<%= dropdown_menu, class: 'teste' do %>
    <%= menu_item "Teste", "fa fa-icon", teste_path %>
    <%= menu_item "Teste", "fa fa-icon", teste_path %>
    <%= menu_item "Teste", "fa fa-icon", teste_path %>
<% end %>
```

Alguém poderia dar um exemplo, ou mesmo um norte de como funciona isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar um parâmetro block e obter o conteúdo do bloco com o método [`capture`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture), como por exemplo:

```
def dropdown_menu(options = {}, &block)
   content_tag(:ul, options) do
     capture(&block)
   end
end
```